# Which "scripting languages" can be compiled to 64-bit?

Tags: .net, scripting, vbscript

I'm looking for a replacement to VBScript that will allow 64-bit compiling. Can you point me to a resource that shows which languages support this?  My Google-Fu seems to be week on this issue.

Comment: On 64-bit Windows, PowerShell defaults to running in a 64-bit process, but a 32-bit executable is available as well...but I'm not sure if that's what you're asking.  You want a scripting language that can be "compiled" to a run-anywhere executable?

Comment: @BACON Not really. I should specify that this is for business application development. Most of the business logic for the applications lives in VBScripts currently.

Comment: If you're switching languages, why keep the restriction of only using "scripting" languages? In any case, the question is an oxymoron - scripting languages aren't normally compiled, which probably explains the difficulties you've had with your Google-fu. To get better answers, you might want to consider describing *what* you'd like to accomplish, rather than *how*.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek Sorry. I wish I had a better way to phrase what I'm looking for. I know scripting languages aren't normally compiled that's why I put it in quotes in the question. Thanks for looking.

Comment: @Splendor: You don't have to phrase what you're looking for better, just explain your current problem, rather than what you think is the solution. Rather than asking for direction this way: "If I take the next right turn, would I be heading north?", instead ask like so: "I'm at Main Street, how do I get from here to Kings Street considering Park Avenue is blocked?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on some OS Ruby does and they are working on the rest

[Is there a 64-bit Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829310/is-there-a-64-bit-ruby)

Ruby is considered a scripting language but it can also be compiled.
I'm switching from Vbscript to Ruby because it is a natural upstep unlike Python which is more difficult to learn (my personal opinion, don't mean to start a war here)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun ... or archive.

The SDF-P language on BS2000 operating system (Siemens/Fujitsu) can be compiled.

```
/COMPILE-PROCEDURE *LIB(TRAMEX.B.LMSLIB,DISPLAY-HELLO),TO=*LIB-ELEMENT
```

where `TRAMEX.B.LMSLIB` is the name of a library (pseuso ZIP or pseudo Folder)
and `DISPLAY-HELLO` is the name of the procedure.

SDF-P language is JCL language (Job Control Language) or script that allows structured programming on BS2000.

An example to display 'Hello' 4 times on console can be

```
/ SET-PROCEDURE-OPTIONS
/ DECLARE-VARIABLE I-COUNT(TYPE=INTEGER, 0)
/ WHILE (I-COUNT < 4)
/     I-COUNT = I-COUNT + 1
/     WRITE-TEXT 'HELLO!'
/ END-WHILE
/ EXIT-PROCEDURE ERROR=*NO
```

This script can be starded using following commands

```
/CALL-PROCEDURE *LIB(TRAMEX.B.LMSLIB,DISPLAY-HELLO)
/CLP *LIB(TRAMEX.B.LMSLIB,DISPLAY-HELLO),LOG=YES
```

This script language is only known on [BS2000 operating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BS2000) system created by Siemens and now sold by Fujitsu.

Current SDF-P documentation can be found on [Fujitsu web documentation site](https://bs2manuals.ts.fujitsu.com/psSDFPV25en).

This language is completely outdated but it contains some special characteristics that any other modern languages don't have.